# Problema con ion-header mode='ios' error de visualización

Tags: ionic, ionic4

Estoy haciendo uso del ion-header en mode ios, el problema es que me di cuenta de este comportamiento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras yo espero que se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que en algunas ocasiones el header aparece en negro, he hecho varias pruebas en mode md y en ese caso nunca surge el problema, me di cuenta que era con el mode ios porque hice otra pantalla en la que se me presentó el mismo problema y no encuentro una solución, en particular me interesa el mode ios porque necesito el modo traslucido que solo se puede acceder de este modo. Para agregar, al recargar varias veces la página algunas veces funciona bien y otras no, generé un apk para validar que no fuera solo en modo web y en el móvil también se repite el comportamiento. Estoy usando Ionic 5.

La parte crítica del código es esta:

```html
<ion-header class="ion-no-border" mode="ios">
  <ion-toolbar style="--background: transparent;">
    <ion-buttons>
      <ion-back-button slot="start" mode="ios" text="" routerLink="/"
        style="color: black;"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-icon slot="end" name="help-circle-outline" color="dark" style="zoom: 3; padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 4px;"
      class="animated pulse infinite" routerLink="/slides-help-create-user"></ion-icon>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

De antemano gracias, estaré a la espera, quisiera saber si alguien más tiene el mismo comportamiento y podamos darle una solución para la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser que este es un bug de Ionic 5, encontré que se podía solucionar desde el apartado de node_modules, se busca el archivo header.ios.scss y se pueden hacer configuraciones, ahí encontré el css que se utiliza para el mode='ios' y para no hacer cambios engorrosos en el node_modules, mejor utilicé ese css para darle la apariencia que quería a mi header y eliminé el mode='ios'. Adjunto los cambios que hice para que tuviera la misma apariencia.

```
ion-toolbar{
   --background: transparent;
   --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
   --opacity: .8;
}
ion-header{
   backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
}
```